# Real URL's in Typo3 9.5.0

Tags: typo3

How can I get URL's like

```
expample.com/home.html
```

in Typo3 950? Typo3 creates only URL's like

```
expample.com/home
```

without `.html`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the default page type by adding a route enhancer in your routing site configuration config.yaml.

```
routeEnhancers:
  PageTypeSuffix:
    type: PageType
    default: '.html'
    map:
      '.html': 0
```

See also here https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.5/Feature-86160-PageTypeEnhancerForMappingTypeParameter.html

More about config.yaml file see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/Basics.html

Comment: Thank you for the code. I add the code to the config.yaml, it works fine for all subpages and subsubpages. But now the link on the logo and the link in the menu for home shows to domian dot com slash index dot html. The canonical link in the sourcecode of home is also domain dot com slash index dot html. A Redirect permanent in .htaccess show me Too many redirects for the domain dot com. The basurl in Typoscript doesn't help. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: This is another question. Have a look at TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\Enhancer\PageTypeDecorator it seems, that there is no way to exclude suffix from root page. Maybe you would create a forge ticket for such a feature here https://forge.typo3.org/issues

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to config.yaml:

```
  routeEnhancers:
    PageTypeSuffix:
      type: PageType
      default: '.html'
      map:
        '.html': 0
```

Then add a redirect in sitemanagement from index.html to example.com